# Считать из файла пароль PowerShell + C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-core

Есть такой скрипт PowerShell

```
string script = @"
$Username = 'admin'
$Password = '1'
$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecurePass
Invoke-Command {Get-Process} -ComputerName 0.0.0.0 -Credential $cred
";
```

Я добавляю его в PowerShell ps и все хорошо работает

```
ps.AddScript(script);
var results = ps.Invoke();
```

Но мне надо пароль считывать из файла, допустим его директива C:\pass.txt
И если я банально меняю строку кода, то не работает((

```
string script = @"
$username = 'admin'
$pass = Get-Content C:\pass.txt
$pass1 = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pass -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$pass1
Invoke-Command {get-process} -ComputerName 0.0.0.0 -Credential $cred
";
```

Я перепробовал много разных вариантов, и подозреваю, что как-то неправильно пишу директиву, то есть кавычки, двойные кавычки, path добавлял, никак не хочет.
Подскажите, если сталкивались, как правильно записать это.
П.С. Вообще изначально я хотел просто сделать скрипт *.ps1 и запустить его через

```
ps.AddScript("C:\\script.ps1").Invoke();
```

но также ни в какую не хочет, сделал скрипт в коде - все работает, но опять же делаю загрузку пароля из файла - не работает, ставлю пароль руками - работает.

Answer (score 1):

Много перерыл в интернете и нашел вариант, который работает, может кому-то пригодится

```
$Password = [IO.File]::ReadAllText('D:\pass.txt')
```

Так считывается пароль, потом уже преобразую его в SecureString и дальше...

Comment: Все равно что-то странное...